# Resizing image and its bounding box

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, math, image-processing

I have an image with bounding box in it, and I want to resize the image.

```
img = cv2.imread("img.jpg",3)
x_ = img.shape[0]
y_ = img.shape[1]
img = cv2.resize(img,(416,416));
```

Now I want to calculate the scale factor:

```
x_scale = ( 416 / x_)
y_scale = ( 416 / y_ )
```

And draw an image, this is the code for the original bounding box:

```
( 128, 25, 447, 375 ) = ( xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
x = int(np.round(128*x_scale))
y = int(np.round(25*y_scale))
xmax= int(np.round  (447*(x_scale)))
ymax= int(np.round(375*y_scale))
```

However using this I get:

[image]

While the original is:

[image]

I don't see any flag in this logic, what's wrong?

Whole code:

```
imageToPredict = cv2.imread("img.jpg",3)
print(imageToPredict.shape)

x_ = imageToPredict.shape[0]
y_ = imageToPredict.shape[1]

x_scale = 416/x_
y_scale = 416/y_
print(x_scale,y_scale)
img = cv2.resize(imageToPredict,(416,416));
img = np.array(img);


x = int(np.round(128*x_scale))
y = int(np.round(25*y_scale))
xmax= int(np.round  (447*(x_scale)))
ymax= int(np.round(375*y_scale))
Box.drawBox([[1,0, x,y,xmax,ymax]],img)
```

and drawbox

```
def drawBox(boxes, image):
    for i in range (0, len(boxes)):
        cv2.rectangle(image,(boxes[i][2],boxes[i][3]),(boxes[i][4],boxes[i][5]),(0,0,120),3)
    cv2.imshow("img",image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image and the data for the bounding box are loaded separately. I am drawing the bounding box inside the image. The image does not contain the box itself.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49466033/edit) to include more information.  Where is `Box.drawBox` defined?  I don't see it in the numpy or opencv docs.

Comment: I deleted that line, its irelavant here

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Would you please adapt the code to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it?  Is the bounding box part of the image data of your original image, or is it something you are drawing separately?

Comment: i have Image, and xml dokument to it where the x, y, width, and height is stored. It is not  important how i load image/xml dokument here i think,  when i resize image, i need to resize the bounding box too

Comment: OK, so the bounding box is not in the image, and you need to resize the bounding box separately from the image.  In that case, the `drawBox` call is definitely relevant :) .  As I said, please give me an MCVE and I'll take a look.  Right now I am afraid it's not jumping out at me from the code snippets.  Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks inconsistent `width` is calculated basing on `xmax` which looks strange. Could you actually show a full example including how you draw both boxes on the full and the scaled images?

Comment: edited question

Comment: It seems to me that you have swapped x and y somewhere, either in the computation of the scaling or in the drawing of the box.

Comment: @jejjejd, I still can't see a piece of code that draws the box over the original image. We can talk about consistency only if you show code for  how **_both_** boxes are drawn. Particularly on your "original" image the frame is not a rect `(128,25)` - `(447,375)`. The actual top-left  corner is something about `(160,35)`

Answer (score 31):

I believe there are two issues:

1. You should swap `x_` and `y_` because `shape[0]` is actually y-dimension and `shape[1]` is the x-dimension
2. You should use the same coordinates on the original and scaled image. On your original image the rectangle is `(160, 35)` - `(555, 470)` rather than `(128,25)` - `(447,375)` that you use in the code.

If I use the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def drawBox(boxes, image):
    for i in range(0, len(boxes)):
        # changed color and width to make it visible
        cv2.rectangle(image, (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]), (boxes[i][4], boxes[i][5]), (255, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.imshow("img", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def cvTest():
    # imageToPredict = cv2.imread("img.jpg", 3)
    imageToPredict = cv2.imread("49466033\\img.png ", 3)
    print(imageToPredict.shape)

    # Note: flipped comparing to your original code!
    # x_ = imageToPredict.shape[0]
    # y_ = imageToPredict.shape[1]
    y_ = imageToPredict.shape[0]
    x_ = imageToPredict.shape[1]

    targetSize = 416
    x_scale = targetSize / x_
    y_scale = targetSize / y_
    print(x_scale, y_scale)
    img = cv2.resize(imageToPredict, (targetSize, targetSize));
    print(img.shape)
    img = np.array(img);

    # original frame as named values
    (origLeft, origTop, origRight, origBottom) = (160, 35, 555, 470)

    x = int(np.round(origLeft * x_scale))
    y = int(np.round(origTop * y_scale))
    xmax = int(np.round(origRight * x_scale))
    ymax = int(np.round(origBottom * y_scale))
    # Box.drawBox([[1, 0, x, y, xmax, ymax]], img)
    drawBox([[1, 0, x, y, xmax, ymax]], img)


cvTest()
```

and use your "original" image as "49466033\img.png",

[image: Original image]

I get the following image

[image: Processed image]

And as you can see my thinner blue line lies exactly inside your original red line and it stays there whatever `targetSize` you chose (so the scaling actually works correctly).

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing this is to use [CHITRA](https://github.com/aniketmaurya/chitra)

```
image = Chitra(img_path, box, label)
# Chitra can rescale your bounding box automatically based on the new image size.
image.resize_image_with_bbox((224, 224))

print('rescaled bbox:', image.bounding_boxes)
plt.imshow(image.draw_boxes())
```

https://chitra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> pip install chitra

Comment: CHITRA looks nifty. It appears that the underlying implementation for this is in the `imgaug` library and an example of how to do this with `imgaug` is here: https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_bounding_boxes.html?highlight=bbs#projection-of-bbs-onto-rescaled-images

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue with bounding box coordinates in Angular when using TensorFlow.js and MobileNet-v2 for prediction. The coordinates were based on the resolution of the video frame.

but I was displaying the video on a canvas with a fixed height and width. I resolved the issue by dividing the coordinates by the ratio of the original video resolution to the resolution of the canvas.

```
      const x = prediction.bbox[0] / (this.Owidth / 300);
      const y = prediction.bbox[1] / (this.Oheight / 300);
      const width = prediction.bbox[2] / (this.Owidth / 300);
      const height = prediction.bbox[3] / (this.Oheight / 300);
      // Draw the bounding box.
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#99ff00';
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
```

- `this.Owidth & this.Oheight` are original resolution of video. it is obtained by.

```
this.video.addEventListener(
      'loadedmetadata',
      (e: any) => {
        this.Owidth = this.video.videoWidth;
        this.Oheight = this.video.videoHeight;
        console.log(this.Owidth, this.Oheight, ' pixels ');
      },
      false
    );
```

- `300 X 300` is my static canvas width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Using [imgaug](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/installation.html) library (thanks to the comment of @Ryaminal)

```
import imgaug as ia
from imgaug.augmentables.bbs import BoundingBox, BoundingBoxesOnImage
import cv2
import matplotlib.image

size=384  # we want to resize to 384x384
image = cv2.imread('xx.jpg')

# say the bounding box is given in (x,y,w,h) format
x=1493
y=1254
w=805
h=381

bbs = BoundingBoxesOnImage([BoundingBox(x1=x, x2=x+w, y1=y, y2=y+h)], shape=image.shape)

# Rescale image and bounding boxes
image_rescaled = ia.imresize_single_image(image, (size, size))
bbs_rescaled = bbs.on(image_rescaled)

new_x1 = round(bbs_rescaled[0].x1)
new_y1 = round(bbs_rescaled[0].y1)
new_x2 = round(bbs_rescaled[0].x2) - round(bbs_rescaled[0].x1)
new_y2 = round(bbs_rescaled[0].y2) - round(bbs_rescaled[0].y1)

new_w = new_x2 - new_x1
new_h = new_y2 - new_y1

matplotlib.image.imsave('rescaled.jpg', image_rescaled) # if you want to save the resized image

# Draw image before/after rescaling and with rescaled bounding boxes
image_bbs = bbs.draw_on_image(image, size=2)
image_rescaled_bbs = bbs_rescaled.draw_on_image(image_rescaled, size=2)

ia.imshow(image_rescaled_bbs)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the [resize_dataset_pascalvoc](https://github.com/italojs/resize_dataset_pascalvoc)

it's easy to use `python3 main.py -p <IMAGES_&_XML_PATH> --output <IMAGES_&_XML> --new_x <NEW_X_SIZE> --new_y <NEW_X_SIZE> --save_box_images <FLAG>"`

It resize all your dataset and rewrite new annotations files to resized images

Comment: you might wanna explain in a little detail how to do it.