# Resize bounding box according to image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am implementing object localisation in Python. A problem I am having is that when I resize the observable region upon taking an action, I do not know how to change the ground truth box at the same time. Consequently, this occurs:

[image: Ex1]

The ground truth box doesn't resize to fit the plane accurately. Thus, I cannot localize properly. My current function for formatting the next state is as follows:

```
def next_state(init_input, b, b_prime, g, a):
    """ 
    Returns the observable region of the next state.

    Formats the next state's observable region, defined
    by b_prime, to be of dimension (224, 224, 3). Adding 16
    additional pixels of context around the original bounding box.
    The ground truth box must be reformatted according to the
    new observable region.

    :param init_input:
        The initial input volume of the current episode.

    :param b:
        The current state's bounding box.

    :param b_prime:
        The subsequent state's bounding box.

    :param g:
        The ground truth box of the target object.

    :param a:
        The action taken by the agent at the current step.
    """

    # Determine the pixel coordinates of the observable region for the following state
    context_pixels = 16
    x1 = max(b_prime[0] - context_pixels, 0)
    y1 = max(b_prime[1] - context_pixels, 0)
    x2 = min(b_prime[2] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)
    y2 = min(b_prime[3] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)

    # Determine observable region
    observable_region = cv2.resize(init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2], (224, 224))

    # Difference between crop region and image dimensions
    x1_diff = x1
    y1_diff = y1
    x2_diff = IMG_SIZE - x2
    y2_diff = IMG_SIZE - y2

    # Resize ground truth box
    g[0] = int(g[0] - 0.5 * x1_diff)  # x1
    g[1] = int(g[1] - 0.5 * y1_diff)  # y1
    g[2] = int(g[2] + 0.5 * x2_diff)  # x2
    g[3] = int(g[3] + 0.5 * y2_diff)  # y2

    return observable_region, g
```

I just cannot seem to get the change in dimensions correct. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466033/resizing-image-and-its-bounding-box) post in order to initially resize the bounding boxes. Yet that solution doesn't seem to be working in this case.

Bounding box/ground truth box are formatted as: `b = [x1, y1, x2, y2]`

`init_input` is of dimensions `(224, 224, 3)`. `IMG_SIZE = 224` and `context_pixels = 16`

Here is an additional example:

[image: Ex3]

It seems as if the size of the ground truth box is correct, however the location is off.

### Update

I have updated the code section above. Scale factor seemed to be the wrong way to approach the problem. By just adding/subtracting the number of pixels to be up-scaled, I have gotten a lot closer. I believe now there is something to do with interpolation, so if anyone could help out with that to make it perfect that would be a huge help.

New example:

[image: ExNew]

### Update 2

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229202/python-opencv-resize-interpolation/51229351?noredirect=1#comment89443051_51229351) was provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python OpenCV resize (interpolation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229202/python-opencv-resize-interpolation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved within [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229202/python-opencv-resize-interpolation/51229351?noredirect=1#comment89443051_51229351) post by a user named @lenik.

Before applying the scale factor to the ground truth box `g`'s pixel coordinates, you must firstly subtract the zero offset so that `x1, y1` becomes `0, 0`. This allows scaling to work properly.

Thus, the coordinates of any random point `(x,y)` after the transformation can be calculated as:

```
x_new = (x - x1) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1)
y_new = (y - y1) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1)
```

In code and in relation to my problem, the solution is as follows:

```
def next_state(init_input, b_prime, g):
    """
    Returns the observable region of the next state.

    Formats the next state's observable region, defined
    by b_prime, to be of dimension (224, 224, 3). Adding 16
    additional pixels of context around the original bounding box.
    The ground truth box must be reformatted according to the
    new observable region.

    :param init_input:
        The initial input volume of the current episode.

    :param b_prime:
        The subsequent state's bounding box.

    :param g:
        The ground truth box of the target object.
    """

    # Determine the pixel coordinates of the observable region for the following state
    context_pixels = 16
    x1 = max(b_prime[0] - context_pixels, 0)
    y1 = max(b_prime[1] - context_pixels, 0)
    x2 = min(b_prime[2] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)
    y2 = min(b_prime[3] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)

    # Determine observable region
    observable_region = cv2.resize(init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2], (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Resize ground truth box 
    g[0] = int((g[0] - x1) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))  # x1
    g[1] = int((g[1] - y1) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))  # y1
    g[2] = int((g[2] - x1) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))  # x2
    g[3] = int((g[3] - y1) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))  # y2

    return observable_region, g
```