# Python OpenCV resize (interpolation)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am resizing an image `init_input` along with a bounding box of a target object `g` within that image to perform object localisation. I am currently resizing the bounding box by determining how many pixels will be up-sampled and adding half of them to each of the bounding box coordinates.

My code is as follows:

```
def next_state(init_input, b_prime, g):
    """ 
    Returns the observable region of the next state.

    Formats the next state's observable region, defined
    by b_prime, to be of dimension (224, 224, 3). Adding 16
    additional pixels of context around the original bounding box.
    The ground truth box must be reformatted according to the
    new observable region.

    :param init_input:
        The initial input volume of the current episode.

    :param b_prime:
        The subsequent state's bounding box. RED

    :param g:
        The ground truth box of the target object. YELLOW
    """

    # Determine the pixel coordinates of the observable region for the following state
    context_pixels = 16
    x1 = max(b_prime[0] - context_pixels, 0)
    y1 = max(b_prime[1] - context_pixels, 0)
    x2 = min(b_prime[2] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)
    y2 = min(b_prime[3] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)

    # Determine observable region
    observable_region = cv2.resize(init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2], (224, 224))

    # Difference between crop region and image dimensions
    x1_diff = x1
    y1_diff = y1
    x2_diff = IMG_SIZE - x2
    y2_diff = IMG_SIZE - y2

    # Resize ground truth box
    g[0] = int(g[0] - 0.5 * x1_diff)  # x1
    g[1] = int(g[1] - 0.5 * y1_diff)  # y1
    g[2] = int(g[2] + 0.5 * x2_diff)  # x2
    g[3] = int(g[3] + 0.5 * y2_diff)  # y2

    return observable_region, g
```

The problem I am having is that this method is not accurate. As evident in the example below, the bounding box is still off. My idea is that this is due to the way interpolation works within the resizing of the image (therefore there is a skew between the pixels taken which is not `0.5`). Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

[image: Example]

### Working example thanks to lenik

[image: Working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's a good idea to scale equally in both dimensions, to preserve the round and square shapes from squashing. So first, you have to find the scale. You do that by finding the largest size of your bounding box and adding 32 (16 pixels on both sides), so:

```
longest = max( x_size, y_size) + 32
scale = 224.0 / longest
```

Then you find your corners by calculating the center of the bounding box and adding half of the `longest` in all directions:

```
center_x = (x1 + x2) / 2
center_y = (y1 + y2) / 2

org_x1 = center_x - longest/2
org_x2 = center_x + longest/2

org_y1 = center_y - longest/2
org_y2 = center_y + longest/2
```

Then you rescale the rectangle with coordinates (org_x1, org_y1, org_x2, org_y2) into (224,224) rectangle and the corners of your bounding box will be `16.0 * scale` offsets from the image corners.

---

ok, as far as I can see, you resize `init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2]` into `(224,224)` and wonder, where ground truth region is going to be. Well, originally ground truth rectangle was 16 pixels from the corners, so you have to find these new offsets and you're done.

```
x_offset = 16.0 * 224.0 / (x2-x1)
y_offset = 16.0 * 224.0 / (y2-y1)
```

then the ground truth rectangle will have left top at (x_offset, y_offset) and bottom right at ((224 - x_offset), (224 - y_offset))

You may ignore the rest of my code written above divider, it was written in assumption that you're preserving the x/y ratio, which you are not =)

---

Here's the third attempt to figure out what you're doing... if you scale `init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2]` into `(224,224)`, the coordinates of any random point (x,y) after the transformation can be calculated as:

```
x_new = (x - x1) * 224.0 / (x2 - x1)
y_new = (y - y1) * 224.0 / (y2 - y1)
```

It might be a good idea to min/max new values against image size, so you don't fall off the image border:

```
x_new = max( 0, min( 224, x_new))
y_new = max( 0, min( 224, y_new))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I don't believe I am understanding your solution properly. I have added a section above 'Update' where I have attempted to implement your solution. However it scales the bounding box incorrectly. Can you please clarify

Comment: I am reshaping the image with respect to the red box `b`/`b_prime`, and just wanting to change `g` the yellow ground truth box according to that reshape.

Comment: what are `b`, `b_prime`, `g` and `a` in your code ? as far as I can see `a` and `b` are never user, `g` is likely `ground_truth`, and I'm still unclear what `b_prime` is for?

Comment: I have updated my post for clarity so I hope you now understand the variables. I am performing RL, thus when I take an action `a` it alters the bounding box `b` (shown in red). I then wish to resize the observable region based upon `b_prime` (which is the bounding box `b` after an action `a` has altered it in some way) plus, and additional 16 pixels of context. NOTE: some, none, or all pixels of context may be added as I use `max()` to make sure that I do not get a pixel dimensions greater than `IMG_SIZE = 224`. So, after cropping the image, based upon `b_prime` and the context pixels, ...

Comment: ... upscale back to dimensions `224 by 224`. Now here is my problem. I have a ground truth box (shown in yellow) which represents the true region of a target object in the image. However, when I crop and then upscale the image, the bounding box obviously moves. Now, I do not know how to properly scale this ground truth box `g` so that it still shows the region where the target object is (as shown in the example it is a bit off).

Comment: I hope you now understand, and I would love to hear any further advice as I have been at this for days and haven't got it yet.

Comment: do you scale (15pixels + bounding box + 15 pixels) into 224 ?

Comment: I scale by firstly cropping the initial image of dimensions (224, 224) by `y1:y2, x1:x2` and then scale back up to (224, 224) as seen below `# Determine observable region`. Also sorry, `b_prime` and `g` are formatted as follows `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`

Comment: `context_pixels=16` so that is sometimes involved in scaling. However it may not add any pixels as I said above since I use `max()`. Say for example if `x2=224`, no additional pixels will be added to `x2`

Comment: It works!!! I cannot thank you enough. Why must we do `(x - x1) * ...` and  `(y - y1) * ...` ? A few days ago I was trying just `224.0 / (x2 - x1)` as a scale factor but it wasn't working

Comment: @Wizard before applying the scale factor, you have to subtract the zero offset. the upper left corner at (x1, y1) becomes (0,0) after that and scaling starts to work.