# Resizing images without changing annotations

Tags: python, object-detection

I have a few thousand annotated images that are of different sizes. I would like to resize them to make them the same size. However, this would make the bounding box coordinates of the annotated objects in the images to be invalid. Is there a way, I can resize the image but ensure that the coordinates would still be valid?

Comment: Please follow this [Resizing image and its bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468149/9531058)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [Resizing image and its bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468149/9531058)

The snippet from the above link:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def drawBox(boxes, image):
    for i in range(0, len(boxes)):
        # changed color and width to make it visible
        cv2.rectangle(image, (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]), (boxes[i][4], boxes[i][5]), (255, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.imshow("img", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def cvTest():
    # imageToPredict = cv2.imread("img.jpg", 3)
    imageToPredict = cv2.imread("49466033\\img.png ", 3)
    print(imageToPredict.shape)

    # Note: flipped comparing to your original code!
    # x_ = imageToPredict.shape[0]
    # y_ = imageToPredict.shape[1]
    y_ = imageToPredict.shape[0]
    x_ = imageToPredict.shape[1]

    targetSize = 416
    x_scale = targetSize / x_
    y_scale = targetSize / y_
    print(x_scale, y_scale)
    img = cv2.resize(imageToPredict, (targetSize, targetSize));
    print(img.shape)
    img = np.array(img);

    # original frame as named values
    (origLeft, origTop, origRight, origBottom) = (160, 35, 555, 470)

    x = int(np.round(origLeft * x_scale))
    y = int(np.round(origTop * y_scale))
    xmax = int(np.round(origRight * x_scale))
    ymax = int(np.round(origBottom * y_scale))
    # Box.drawBox([[1, 0, x, y, xmax, ymax]], img)
    drawBox([[1, 0, x, y, xmax, ymax]], img)


cvTest()
```

Original image :

[image]

Resized

[image]

Hope this solves your question.